# error : The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Am having an error which  The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

```
 List <UserModel> Userdata = [];
  Future<List<UserModel>> getAPiCalling ()async{
     final response =await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
     var data =jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

     if(response.statusCode == 200){
           for (Map i in data){
            Userdata.add(UserModel.fromJson(i));
           }
           return Userdata;
     }
     else 
     return Userdata;
  }
```

Comment: Can you the response item structure and `UserModel`

Comment: yes i response item structure and UserModel

Comment: sorry, Can you include the `UserModel` i n question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by type definition. By default Map takes <dynamic, dynamic>. Your model I presume is Map<String, dynamic>. For this reason, you need to cast (force) the json data to match your model pattern. Use this code

```
if(response.statusCode == 200){ 
   for (Map i in data) { 
   Userdata.add(UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(i)));
   } 
 return Userdata; 
}
```